# file_get_contents expects a string

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a file from s3 and move it to my local file system and I am getting this error

> file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

```
$upload_directory = "C:\wamp\test";

$s3 = new AmazonS3("key", "pass");



$source = $s3->getObject("bucket","file.mp3");
$destination = "C:\wamp\test\file.mp3";

$data = file_get_contents($source);

$handle = fopen($destination, "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Where does the `AmazonS3` class come from? And where is the documentation for that class? And while you're at it: what does the documentation say about the `getObject` method of that class?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing it an object apparently, var_dump($source) to see the kind of data you are getting back first. it needs to be a string

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `AmazonS3::getObject()` does not return a string. Does the object returned from `getObject()` offer a URL string method or property?

**Edit:** I know this isn't what you're using but [amazon-s3-php-class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) appears to offer a much simpler interface for saving an S3 object locally.

Comment: +1 yep, saw that third argument there. It appears they are trying to request it and then save it locally. `file_put_contents()` would be easier anyway :)

Comment: Hi phil. I see in the object that there is a url. not sure how i can use it to get the file

Answer (score 0):

see if the return object has a __toString() function that you can call. If it returns the path of the file, then you can use it in the function file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the object into a string.

```
$source = (string) $s3->getObject("bucket","file.mp3");
```

Comment: That's very presumptuous unless you know where the mysterious `AmazonS3` class comes from

Comment: Agreed.  This only works if you know $source contains the data you want.  Use the above suggestion of var_dump to ensure it does.  If not:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/

Answer (score 0):

Casting to string won't work for the object returned from $s3->getObject. If you need a string back from $s3->getObject, do this instead:

```
$image = $s3->getObject($bucket, "file.jpg");
if ($image->body) {
    return $image->body;
} else {
    return '';
}
```